# How to get Ledger Nano S to work in an Ubuntu VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, hardware-wallet, ledger-hardware-wallet

I installed the ledger manager on Ubuntu VirtualBox, but I can't see any of my USB devices. My host OS is Windows 10. How do I get this to work?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the udev rules (on the guest OS) with this command:

```
wget -q -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LedgerHQ/udev-rules/master/add_udev_rules.sh | sudo bash
```

It works, I verified it.

source: https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005165269